# Get-NetTCPConnection And netstat do not list docker's exposed port

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose

I'm using a docker application that runs on port 8080 inside docker. Using `docker-compose.yaml`, I've published port 10000 on the host machine and directed its traffic to port 8080. The application seems to be working file. I can open my browser, visit localhost:10000 and see the web UI.

But, when I try to list down the open ports using `netstat -a` or Powershell's `Get-NetTCPConnection` cmdlet, I see the port in the list. Here's what I've tried:

1. Open command prompt as administrator and run `netstat -a`.
2. Open Powershell as administrator (I'm using Powershell 7.0.0), run `Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen`
3. Verify the service is running by visiting localhost:10000 (Yep! It's running)
4. Of course, the host I'm using to visit the page and where I'm running the command are the same.

Not sure if it makes any difference but, I'm using Windows 10 host, Windows containers and docker's NAT network adapter to create the application's virtual network. The docker version is `Docker version 18.09.8, build 90e30bdf98`.

Any pointers or suggestions will be appreciated.